# Binary tree operator deep copy

Tags: c++, binary-tree, deep-copy

I am trying to do a deep copy using the "=" operator but it seems to be a shallow copy in the way I wrote it and I don't see why it is.
bs2 also added "q" so I can understand it did shallow copy
why is it shallow copy, I expected it to be deep-copying.
how can I change it to deep copy?

```
here is what I tried:
BSNode& BSNode::operator=(const BSNode& other) 
{
    if (this == &other) // tries to copy the object to itself
    {
        return *this;
    }
    delete _left;
    _left = other._left;
    delete _right;
    _right = other._right;

    return *this;
}
```

```
class BSNode
{
public:
    BSNode(std::string data);
    BSNode(const BSNode& other);
    ~BSNode();

    BSNode& operator=(const BSNode& other);

    //some more functions...
private:
    std::string _data;
    BSNode* _left;
    BSNode* _right;
    int _count; count the times an element appears in the tree
};
```

````
    BSNode* bs1 = new BSNode("d");
    bs1->insert("d");
    bs1->insert("b");

    BSNode* bs2 = new BSNode("1");

    bs2 = bs1;
    bs1->insert("q");
    bs2->printNodes(bs2);//bs2 also added "q"
    ```
bs2 also added "q" so I can understand it did shallow copy
why is it shallow copy, I expected it to be deep-copying.
how can I change it to deep copy?
````

Comment: _left = other._left;

performs a simple pointer assignment since the type of `_left` is `BSNode*`. In order to perform an actual reassignment, you'll need to invoke `operator=` on the nodes themselves

Comment: I changed it to:  
 
    delete _left;
    *_left = *other._left;
    delete _right;
    *_right = *other._right;

but it still doesn't work

Comment: Reinstate Monica - ζ-- what do you mean "invoke operator= on the nodes themselves"

Comment: I saw your comment; please be patient as I didn't see it immediately--you need to actually construct new nodes, not (just) delete old ones. Your copy ctor should represent the construction of a new tree altogether. Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually construct new nodes, not (just) delete old ones. If a tree consists of five nodes and you never construct any new nodes, there's no way to have two trees of five nodes after.

Your copy assignment operator ought to represent the construction of a new tree altogether. You can leverage a copy constructor (which you should have via rule-of-three anyway) in that case:

```
BSNode::BSNode(const BSNode& other) {
if(other._left){
      _left = new BSNode(*other._left);
    }
    if(other._right) {
      _right = new BSNode(*other._right);
    }
}

BSNode& BSNode::operator=(const BSNode& other) 
{
    if (this == &other) // tries to copy the object to itself
    {
        return *this;
    }
    delete _left;
    if(other._left){
      _left = new BSNode(*other._left);
    }
    delete _right;
    if(other._right) {
      _right = new BSNode(*other._right);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Here's a comparison showing your incorrect call which just assigns pointers, as compared to an actual object assignment. I assume that your constructor is well-formed, and make private members public since you do not include all of the necessary code for me to quickly test this.

```
int main(){
    // bad
    BSNode* ap = new BSNode("a");
    ap->_left = new BSNode("al");
    BSNode* bp = ap;
    bp->_left = new BSNode("bl");

    std::cout << ap->_left->_data << std::endl;

    // good
    BSNode a("a");
    a._left = new BSNode("al");
    BSNode b(a);
    b._left = new BSNode("bl");
    std::cout << a._left->_data << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how it solves the problem, I created a tree and then copied it to a new one and changed the first one - the new still the same as the first
what I did: 
 BSNode* bs1 = new BSNode("d");
 bs1->insert("h");
BSNode* bs2 = new BSNode("1"); 
bs2 = bs1
bs1->insert("q");

butt bs2 lso added "q" to the ree

Comment: @ויחנ You're not actually invoking your custom `operator=` because you're operating on *pointers* to BSNodes. Either invoke the copy constructor manually, or construct `bs1` and `bs2` with automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

> why is it shallow copy

Because if you assign the pointer member of `this` to point to same object as another instance is pointing at, then you've made a shallow copy.

In order to have a deep copy of a tree, you must create nodes for the copy. If there is no duplicate set of nodes, then a duplicate (deep) copy of the tree doesn't exist. Nowhere in your assignment operator do you create any nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Think recursively when you are writing algorithms for recursive data structures.

First define your concepts:

> **Clone of a node A** is:
>
> - Empty if **A** is empty, or
> - A new node whose data is the copy of **A**'s data, left is **Clone of A's left node**, and right is **Clone of A's right node** otherwise.

This can be translated into a helper method:

```cpp
BSNode* clone_node(const BSNode* src) {
    if (src == nullptr) return nullptr;
    BSNode* clonedNode = new BSNode(src.data);
    clonedNode.left = clone_node(src.left);
    clonedNode.right = clone_node(src.right);
    return clonedNode;
}
```

Now you can express your `operator=` as following:

```cpp
BSNode& BSNode::operator=(const BSNode& other) 
{
    if (this == &other) // tries to copy the object to itself
    {
        return *this;
    }
    this->data = other.data;
    delete this->left;
    delete this->right;
    this->left = clone_node(other.left);
    this->right = clone_node(other.right);
    return *this;
}
```

However, if your left (or right) node is not `nullptr`, you can reuse them (rather than allocating a new node). Write another helper method:

```cpp
void clone_to(BSNode*& dest, const BSNode* src) {
    if (dest != nullptr && src != nullptr) {
        *dest = *src;
    }
    else {
        delete dest;
        dest = clone_node(src);
    }
}
```

Now you can write the final version of your `operator=`:

```cpp
BSNode& BSNode::operator=(const BSNode& other) 
{
    if (this == &other) // tries to copy the object to itself
    {
        return *this;
    }
    this->data = other.data;
    clone_to(this->left, other.left);
    clone_to(this->right, other.right);
    return *this;
}
```